# Multiply two numbers without using multiplication

Tags: javascript, data-structures, logic

I have a test, where I needed to code for multiplying two numbers without using multiplication,

the code is as follows,

```
function multiply(num,toNum){
  var product = 0;
  for(var i = 1; i <= toNum; i++){
    product += num;
  }

  return product;
}

console.log(multiply(2,5));
```

The output is

```
rahul@rahul:~/myPractise/Algo$ node MultiplyWithoutLoop.js 
10 
rahul@rahul:~/myPractise/Algo$
```

Is the above code satisfactory or need is there a room for improvement.

Can a better logic be applied.

Hey,

I solved it using recursion,

this is the code,

```
function multiply01(num,toNum){
  var product = num;    
  return (toNum >= 1) ? product + multiply01(product,--toNum) : 0; 
}
```

Comment: if this works properly, you are probably better posting this on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ but one way to make it better is to use the lower number for the loop

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about code review -- can we move it to there instead?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use addition for odd numbers and and bit shifting. Better known as [Ancient Egyptian multiplication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ancient_Egyptian_multiplication).

The value of `b` is summed, if `a` is odd. Then `a` is divided by 2 and the integer part is assigned. `b` is doubled.

Example:

```
 a    b   sum
---  ---  ---
  5    4    4  add 4
  2    8    4
  1   16   20  add 16
  0   32   20  <- result
```

```js
function multiply(a, b) {
    var sum = 0;
    while (a) {
        if (a & 1) {
            sum += b;
        }
        a >>= 1;
        b <<= 1;
    }
    return sum;
}

console.log(multiply(5, 4));
console.log(multiply(3, 7));
console.log(multiply(191, 7));
```

Answer (score 9):

Compact way:

```
function multiply(a, b) {
  return a / (1 / b);
}

console.log(multiply(2, 5)); // 10
```

Comment: Haha lol, that appears to be valid :D

Comment: Wrong results on `b = 0`

Comment: Needs a special case to handle `b` is 0, but other than that, this is the winner. I'd go with a ternary for that.

Comment: Does it really need a special case for `b == 0`? Could someone provide exact values for parameters when `return a / (1 / b);` does not return expected results?

Comment: @Pimgd "Needs a special case to handle b is 0" --- does it?

Comment: @zerkms if you have `1 / 0`, what do you think that will happen?

Comment: @Pimgd exactly what is described in IEEE754. A hint: what if you try before you continue this dialogue? `1 / (1 / 0)` --- what do you think it will return? Another hint: it would return `0` exactly as one would expect.

Comment: @zerkms Huh... alright, trying now. ... Okay, it doesn't crash and it does work. I'm too much used to general programming, where in some cases, things will throw errors at you for dividing by 0, and in others, it will not. Thus I prefer to manually handle divisions by 0 myself. ... But yeah, you could leave it out in this case?...

Comment: @Pimgd literally every language that implements IEEE754 for floating point numbers (and that is literally every language?) would behave like that.

Comment: @zerkms ColdFusion doesn't =/ God I hate that language

Answer (score 1):

Please try this, it will also handle **negative value**

```
function multiply(x, y)
{
    /* Add x one by one */
    if(y > 0 )
    {
        return (x + multiply(x, y-1));
    }

    /* the case where y is negative */
    else if(y < 0 )
    {
        return -multiply(x, -y);
    }

    return 0;
}
```